# VLCJ Start-Time before playing a movie file

Tags: java, javafx, vlc, vlcj

I test the vlcj wrapper to play movies in a Java application. It seems that the integration is very simple and the performance is good, but I have a problem. When I pause a movie, I save the pause time. When I play the movie, I use the saved pause time as the start time. I have not found a way to set the start time before the film, so that the film really starts from the start time. At the moment, the first frames of a video are played before the start time is jumped. That is a big problem. I need to play the video exactly from the pause time and do not want to see the first frames of a video.

I tried the vlcj wrapper, because i will play 4k media files. The internal JavaFX Mediaplayer, which i have tested first can´t play this media files.

Does somebody has any idea?

greetings
MS-Tech

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I have understood what you want to do but have you tried to use the
`MediaPlayer.getTime();`
and
`MediaPlayer.setTime(long time);`
to set start and stop positions?

If that is what you are asking would'nt it be possible to just do `MediaPlayer.setTime(long time);` before the `MediaPlayer.play();`?

Comment: You can't invoke setTime, at least not with any useful effect, until after the media has started playing.

Comment: okay, does the MediaPlayer.skip(long) method work similar? Also I think this should be mentioned in the documentation about those methods in that case..